# kubernetes and external DNS in ubuntu

Tags: kubernetes, dns, dnsmasq, kube-dns

I have an ubuntu box out of the kubernetes cluster

My /etc/resolv.conf content

```
nameserver 10.3.0.1 (kubedns)
```

If i make a nslookup, everything works fine

```
nslookup spark-master-0.spark-master.ns.svc.cluster.local
Server:     10.3.0.1
Address:    10.3.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   spark-master-0.spark-master.ns.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.2.0.252
```

if i try to use any other tool (chrome, curl, ping, wget) i get an error:

```
curl spark-master-0.spark-master.ns.svc.cluster.local
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: spark-master-0.spark-master.ns.svc.cluster.local
```

The only way is to add search .cluster.local in /etc/resolv.conf, but now i cannot use the fqdn of the nodes

any tip on how to use the fqdn ?

**Update** The same setup in my mac works perfect ! the problem is only with my ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: Would you please post both versions of `/etc/resolv.conf`, the one that works and the one that does not? Please add as little obfuscation as possible.

Comment: nameserver 10.3.0.1, it's the same file in both my ubuntu and my mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like FQDN is working fine with DNS but issue with the host system.

Can you try after changing the below entry in /etc/nsswitch.conf.

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

to

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return]
```

if above also not work then try putting only DNS.

```
hosts:          dns [NOTFOUND=return]
```

Comment: i'll try tomorrow from the office

Comment: This is the solution hosts: files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return]